# Making upstart job redirect output as unprivileged user

Tags: root, privileges, init, upstart

I am currently making an upstart job run as an unprivileged user like so:

```
start on started mongodb
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn
respawn limit 10 100

env NODE_ENV=production

pre-start script
    ulimit -n 2048
end script

exec sudo -u mainuser /usr/bin/make -C /home/mainuser/app start-prod >> /home/mainuser/data/logs/app.log 2>> /home/mainuser/data/logs/app.err.log
```

This works good, with one exception: the log files `app.log` and `app.err.log` are being written as root (root becomes the owner of these files).

How do I ensure that the log files are written by the unprivileged `mainuser`?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts from the top of my head: you could use `| sudo -u mainuser tee` to write the file (but if you want to split STDOUT and STDERR it can [become a bit messy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)), or you could in the script check if the log files exist and are owned by `mainuser`, if not create and `chown mainuser`. Then appending output as you do would keep ownership.

Quick snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
user="mainuser"
group="mainuser"
for i in /home/mainuser/data/logs/app.log /home/mainuser/data/logs/app.err.log; do
    if [ ! -f "${i}" ] || [ "$(stat -c%U -- "${i}")" != "${user}" ]; then
        touch -- "${i}"
        chown ${user}:${group} -- "${i}"
    fi
done
```

This is quick and doesn't handle cases such as the log files existing as directories/links and so on very nicely, but in practice it might be fine.

I haven't worked with Upstart though, so maybe there are simpler ways.

Comment: I don't think an unprivileged user can "steal" or chown a file owned by root. The `tee` hint is more interesting, but before I try to implement it I will wait and see if there are any better options available, if you don't mind. Maybe I should just modify my make script so that it will do the logging.

Comment: @Tom: You run the above test _as_ root in the upstart script, in the `pre-start script` section I would guess, before dropping privilege to `mainuser`. Only root can `chown` as well.